# multiple checkbox update with row

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

[i have this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCwz0.jpg)

how do i update this record by row with checkbox ? the checkbox hold a value i sent from previous form .

[this would be the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bHED.jpg)

is this right??

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

.
.
.
.

```
    <td><center>
    <input type="hidden" name="matric[]" value="<?php echo $matric?>"/><p>
      <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" value='$hour' name="unattend<?php echo $matric?>[]">
      <label> Unattend</label></p> </center></td>
    <td><center>
    <input type="hidden" name="matric[]" value="<?php echo $matric?>"/><p>
      <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" value='$hour' name="mc<?php echo $matric?>[]">
      <label> I have MC </label></p> </center></td>   }
```

how would the update mysql be ?

Comment: try to formulate your problems more clearly - how it should work, what you tried, and what does not work. post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the form

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row['matric_number'];
?>

 <form method="POST" action="attend.php">
<tr>
<td><center><?php echo $i; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['matric_number']; ?></center></td>
<td><center>
<p>
<input class="w3-check" name="unattend[]" type="checkbox" id="unattend[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
 <label> Unattend</label></p> </center></td>
<td><center>
<p>
  <input class="w3-check" name="mc[]" type="checkbox" id="mc[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <label> I have MC </label></p> </center></td>
<td><center>
<?php echo "<a href=student.php?id1=".$row['matric_number'].">"."Details"; ?></center></td>



</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}


mysqli_close ($link);
?>
</table>
```

The php to update the data by row is

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['unattend'])) {

$hour=$_POST['hour'];
$id=$_POST['unattend'];
$N = count($id);

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
$select = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM pbu WHERE matric_number='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {

$value=$row['unattend'];
$total=$value+$hour;
$result = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE pbu SET unattend='$total' WHERE matric_number='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
echo "unattend is updated for matric number ".$id[$i]."<br>";



}
}

}
if (isset($_POST['mc'])){
$id1=$_POST['mc'];
$N = count($id1);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
$select = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM pbu WHERE matric_number='$id[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {

$values=$row['mc'];
$totals=$values+$hour;
$results = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE pbu SET mc='$totals' WHERE matric_number='$id1[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
echo "mc is updated for ".$id1[$i]."<br>";

}

}
}
else{
echo "nothing inserted";
}


 ?>
```